# How to manage log_url_info.ibd on magento 1.8.1

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a Magento 1.8.1 in PROD env with the following files:

```
log_url_info.ibd
log_visitor_info.ibd
log_url.ibd
log_visitor.ibd
```

all these files are very large (more than 1 GB).

I executed DB mantainance with following command:

```
`php -f log.php clean --days 15`
```

the table were cleaned,checked with:

```
`php -f log.php status`
```

but the above file are still very large.

It is not very clear why table cleanup doesn't reduce file dimension.

Any suggestion on how to reduce file dimension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was in my.ini configuration file of mysql, setting these parameters I resolved my problem:

```
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
```